# push to JSON Array if Object does not exist

Tags: jquery

I have a JSON as shown below

```
[
  {
    "name": "Mike",
    "incentives": "23.45",
    "id": "1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Larsen",
    "incentives": "34.78",
    "id": "2"
  },
  {
    "name": "Steve",
    "incentives": "26.78",
    "id": "3"
  }
]
```

I need to  push a new JSON Object into the JSON array if id not exists inside the JSON Object

tried as this way and working , any better way of doing this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var idsarray = [];

  var test = [
  {
    "name": "Mike",
    "incentives": "23.45",
    "id": "1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Larsen",
    "incentives": "34.78",
    "id": "2"
  },
  {
    "name": "Steve",
    "incentives": "26.78",
    "id": "3"
  }
];

for(var i=0;i<test.length;i++)
{
idsarray.push(test[i].id)
}

var newobj =  {
    "name": "RAM",
    "incentives": "56.78",
    "id": "4"
  }

  var newid = newobj.id;

if(jQuery.inArray(newid, idsarray) !== -1)
{
test.push(newobj)
}

alert(test.length)

});
```

Comment: your logic is fair enough. only thing is you need to update `idsarray` with new element added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is incorrect. It should be `jQuery.inArray(newid, idsarray) === -1` because the operation `jQuery.inArray(newid, idsarray)` will return `-1` if the `newid` is not present in `idsarray`. So, that is what you need, to check unique occurrence in `idsarray`.

You can also use the `indexOf()` operation for the same. `idsarray.indexOf(newid) === -1`.

**OP's code**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var idsarray = [];
  var test = [{
      "name": "Mike",
      "incentives": "23.45",
      "id": "1"
    },
    {
      "name": "Larsen",
      "incentives": "34.78",
      "id": "2"
    },
    {
      "name": "Steve",
      "incentives": "26.78",
      "id": "3"
    }
  ];

  for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
    idsarray.push(test[i].id)
  }

  var newobj = {
    "name": "RAM",
    "incentives": "56.78",
    "id": "4"
  }

  var newid = newobj.id;
  if (jQuery.inArray(newid, idsarray) === -1) {
    test.push(newobj)
  }
  alert(test.length)

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**USING `indexOf()`**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var idsarray = [];
  var test = [{
      "name": "Mike",
      "incentives": "23.45",
      "id": "1"
    },
    {
      "name": "Larsen",
      "incentives": "34.78",
      "id": "2"
    },
    {
      "name": "Steve",
      "incentives": "26.78",
      "id": "3"
    }
  ];

  for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
    idsarray.push(test[i].id)
  }

  var newobj = {
    "name": "RAM",
    "incentives": "56.78",
    "id": "4"
  }

  var newid = newobj.id;
  if (idsarray.indexOf(newobj) === -1) {
    test.push(newobj)
  }
  alert(test.length)

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`inArray` is slow. If you do this once, it's not the worst thing ever, but `find` or `some` on the original array would be better:

```
if (!test.some(o => o.id == newid)) {
  test.push(newobj)
}
```

However, if you do this often, a much better idea is to make a set, as checking membership in a set is very very fast:

```
let idset = new Set();
...
if (!idset.has(newid)) {
  test.push(newobj);
  idset.add(newid);
}
```

You could also use `Map` (or even plain old object) to combine the two:

```
let test = new Map();
...
if (!test.has(newid)) {
    test.set(newobj);
}
```

You can get the array from the `Map` using `test.values()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the use of another `array` that contains the `id` of objects. You can use native function [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check for existence and push accordingly.

```js
var test = [{"name":"Mike","incentives":"23.45","id":"1"},{"name":"Larsen","incentives":"34.78","id":"2"},{"name":"Steve","incentives":"26.78","id":"3"}];
var newobj = {"name":"RAM","incentives":"56.78","id":"4"};
if(!test.some(({id}) => id == newobj.id)) test.push(newobj);
console.log(test);
```

Also, if your push operation is going to be quite frequent then looping every time will affect the performance. Instead of array of `ids`, you can maintain an `map` or `set` of ids as the complexity of search will be O(1).

```js
var test = [{"name":"Mike","incentives":"23.45","id":"1"},{"name":"Larsen","incentives":"34.78","id":"2"},{"name":"Steve","incentives":"26.78","id":"3"}];
var newobj = {"name":"RAM","incentives":"56.78","id":"4"};
var ids = test.reduce((a, {id}) => Object.assign(a, {[id]:id}), {});
if(!ids[newobj.id]) {
   test.push(newobj);
   ids[newobj.id] = newobj.id;
}
console.log(test);
```